# C# Getting value from a string

Tags: c#, string, foreach, int

I have a string like this

```
string myString = [0,4,5,5,6];
```

and i want to obtain each value of this string through a foreach loop for example , how i can proceed ?

Comment: That looks a bit more like an array with numbers...?

Comment: this is not a string, its an array of integers (if this was javascript of course)

Comment: are you sure that is a string? could it perhaps be a char array where you are specifying the character codes? or did you forget to put the quotes?

Comment: Yes it's a string from an api ( it's not a json)

Comment: In the code block in your question: 1. That is the JSON array syntax. 2. That is not a string. It is also not valid C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you just forgot to put the quotes around the string:

you need to loop through each character and try to parse it into a number

```
//A list to hold the result
List<int> values = new List<int>();

//loop through each character 1 by 1
foreach(var c in myString)
{
     //will hold the value
     int num = 0;

     //Try to parse the character into an integer
     var isNumber = int.TryParse(c.ToString(), out num);

     //if the parsing succeeded add it to the list
     if(isNumber)
     {
         values.Add(num);
     }
}
```

This will output the values 0,4,5,5,6 into the values list, ignoring all non numeric numbers

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use linq like so

```
List<int> = myString.Select(Int32.Parse).ToList();
```